# How to copy the output of linux command to a C++ variable

Tags: c++, linux, command

I'm calling a LINUX command from within a C++ programme which creates the following output. I need to copy the first column of the output to a C++ variable (say a long int). How can I do it?? If that is not possible how can I copy this result into a .txt file with which I can work with?

**Edit**

```
          0 +0
 2361294848 +2361294848
 2411626496 +50331648
 2545844224 +134217728
 2713616384 +167772160
```

I have this stored as a file, file.txt and I'm using the following code to 
extract the left column with out the 0 to store it at integers

```
string stringy="";
int can_can=0;
for(i=begin;i<length;i++)
{
if (buffer[i]==' ' && can_can ==1) //**buffer** is the whole text file read in char*
{
num=atoi(stringy.c_str());
array[univ]=num; // This where I store the values.
univ+=1;
can_can=1;
  }
  else if (buffer[i]==' ' && can_can ==0) 
 {
stringy="";  
}
else if (buffer[i]=='+')
{can_can=0;}
else{stringy.append(buffer[i]);}
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation error for this. What can be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code! How are you running the Linux command?

Comment: how is this output retrieved in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a simple streambuf wrapper around popen()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

struct SimpleBuffer: public std::streambuf
{   
    typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits;
    typedef traits::int_type            int_type;

    SimpleBuffer(std::string const& command)
        : stream(popen(command.c_str(), "r"))
    {   
        this->setg(&c[0], &c[0], &c[0]);
        this->setp(0, 0); 
    }   
    ~SimpleBuffer()
    {   
        if (stream != NULL)
        {   
            fclose(stream);
        }   
    }   
    virtual int_type underflow()
    {   
        std::size_t size = fread(c, 1, 100, stream);
        this->setg(&c[0], &c[0], &c[size]);

        return size == 0 ? EOF : *c; 
    }   

    private:
        FILE*   stream;
        char    c[100];

};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    SimpleBuffer    buffer("echo 55 hi there Loki");
    std::istream    command(&buffer);

    int  value;
    command >> value;

    std::string line;
    std::getline(command, line);

    std::cout << "Got int(" << value << ") String (" << line << ")\n";
}
```

Result:

```
> ./a.out
Got int(55) String ( hi there Loki)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `popen` you're probably looking for. Try

```
man popen
```

.

Or see this little example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];

    if(!(in = popen("my_script_from_command_line", "r"))){
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
          cout << buff; // here you have each line 
                        // of the output of your script in buff
    }
    pclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to execute the command. This will give you a `FILE *` that you can read its output from. From there, you can parse out the first number with (for example) something like:

```
fscanf(inpipe, "%d %*d", &first_num);
```

which, just like when reading from a file, you'll normally repeat until you receive an end of file indication, such as:

```
long total = 0;

while (1 == fscanf(inpipe, "%l %*d", &first_num))
    total = first_num;

printf("%l\n", total);
```

Comment: your `1 == fscanf` seems not right: from man fscanf: '[..] return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, [..]'. Would be 2 in your case, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PatrickB.: No -- the "and assigned" is crucial here. The `*` in the second conversion prevents its result from being assigned.

Comment: ok, I just saw that there was only one argument... and the total == first_num?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it’s not easy since the platform API is written for C. The following is a simple working example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char const* command = "ls -l";

    FILE* fpipe = popen(command, "r");

    if (not fpipe) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to execute commmand\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char buffer[256];
    while (std::fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fpipe)) {
        std::cout << buffer;
    }

    pclose(fpipe);
}
```

However, I’d suggest wrapping the `FILE*` handle in a RAII class to take care of resource management.